# Make a DataFrame with idxmax() outputs

Tags: pandas, list, indexing, max

I am using idxmax to subset the maximum values of my dataframe and get their index values.

I put the output in a list, and convert it into a two-columns dataframe.

Unfortunately, one of the column is interpreted as the index. And using index=False or index=None does not work.

Would anyone know why?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

list=df.idxmax()

df = pd.DataFrame(list, index=False, columns = ['Y', 'Z'])
```

Comment: Try `list.reset_index()` ? Or better yet, `list.rename_axis('Y').reset_index(name='Z')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
list.rename_axis('Y').reset_index(name='Z')
```

Output:

```
   Y   Z
0  A  42
1  B  88
2  C  47
3  D  82
```

---

###### Update:

```
list.rename_axis('Y').rename('Z').to_frame()
```

Output:

```
    Z
Y    
A  42
B  88
C  47
D  82
```

Comment: Thank you @Scott, the list is indeed with the right formatting now.
But when trying to convert it in a dataframe, the Y column is taken as an index with df = pd.DataFrame(list, index=None)

Comment: I don't understand what your desired output is.   Here, we have an dataframe output with two columns. Y is your index and Z is your value.

Comment: Apologizes for the confusion, the questions was not well formulated. I wish to output a dataframe with two columns, Y and Z, as in the list. And no index. So here Y should not be the index of the dataframe.

Comment: Oh!!! try `list.to_frame()` after idxmax.  Or `list.rename_axis('Y').rename('Z').to_frame()`

Comment: Thank you @Scott. It seems that after using df =list.rename_axis('Y').rename('Z'), Python consider df as a dataframe already. So the .to_frame() function is apparently not necessary after all.